# Keep screen position when hide and reload a div with display CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, position

First of all, thanks everyone for paying attention. I have a very especific question.

I charge a few divs in 1 load of my application, these divs are hidden and show them again when I click on some tabs of the screen, the problem is:

I charge all of them, on the first time, all works good, but when I go out of the page and charge it again this keeps the last tab opened but not the position of the screen. To abbreviate, I need a way to keep the position scrolled of the previous screen opened.

Sorry if I explain very bad.

thanks

Comment: So U want 2 tabs, to always stay on the same position when scrolling on 1 of the tabs? Or do u want to scroll to the current position on the tab you open? Or none of those?

Comment: Show us your code, then maybe we can help.